# Set text in div tag with expand to top (vk.com tampermonkey script)

Tags: javascript, html, tampermonkey, vk

During developing of more convenient messages templates for vk.com I faced an issue with message input expanding down instead of expanding up (like it should). [Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=snqO5Kf1FT0)

Despite some amount of time spent on investigating and resolving the issue - I could not find the reason and a way to fix it. [Explaining video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6Uoyrev7y98)

My code to insert text:

```
function setText(text) {
    const chatDiv = document.querySelector("div.im_editable.im-chat-input--text._im_text");
    if (chatDiv) {
        chatDiv.innerText = text;
    }
}
```

Tag which I insert to: [image: html tag]

Comment: Your youtube video is private, please set it to : anyone who has the link.

Comment: I did it already